# Performance: finding newest file in folder

Tags: .net, windows, performance, matlab, file-io

I am trying to (very quickly) find the newest file in a folder under Windows. I'm using Matlab, but solutions using .NET may be useful, as I can probably use that from within Matlab.

The problem here is **performance**. The standard way of solving this is to use `dir` and then find the file with the latest timestamp. However, the folder will grow iteratively into thousands or tens of thousands of files, and the application is performance sensitive.

Using .NET's `GetFiles` has the same issue, reading the entire directory on each pass, which I would like to avoid.

One solution is to use .NET's `FileSystemWatcher`, but in this case I would prefer to not use an event based solution.

Is there some Matlab or .NET based solution to just quickly ask for the latest file inside a folder containing arbitrarily many files?

BTW: I am using R2014a at the moment, which may be relevant.

Comment: You can use lower level Java commands e.g. `java.io.File(...)` from most MATLAB versions which tend to be a little quicker than MATLAB's file functions

Comment: Thanks. `java.io.File` does not seem to be available in R2014a. Do you have any suggestions how to access java in old versions like that?

Comment: I think it should only be newer versions (2021+) which don't have the Java functionality, since MathWorks wanted to stop licensing it. But documentation and tab-completion are non-existant. Can you try something like `java.io.File('C:\Users\DNF\someFolder').exists`? If that works then you would have to look up the required Java functionality to actually achieve your goal

Comment: Oh, it _does_ work. Nice. But now I need to figure out how to find the latest file.

Comment: Yeah I realise that doesn't necessarily help anything, just another avenue to look down

Comment: Java doesn't help any. It's just slower than calling into the OS directly. And calling into the OS has been precluded by the asker, due to enumerating all files and sorting them by last-modified time being allegedly too slow. The only other option, i.e. asking to OS to report file system activities to a callback, has been preemptively rejected as well. Which leaves you with no solutions to your problem.

Comment: Well, that was my question, is there any other way? I don't see the reason for the negative tone, @IInspectable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is useful. Too bad about the tone.